# How can I render a specific template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.9.

I have this action in my `ProcurementsController`...

```
  def view_downloads
    @downloads = Procurement.find(params[:id]).downloads
  end
```

I want to render this view: `views/procurements/view_downloads.html.haml`.

When I just leave it like that what gets rendered is the Procurements index page. (I thought is was supposed to render the template with the same name as the action by default.)

I looked in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) for the render method and found this...

> Method deprecated
>
> This method is deprecated on the latest stable version of Rails. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here.

Zero info about what to use instead, or where to get further information.

Does that mean it's deprecated in Rails 3 but I can still use it if I'm using 2.x?

Or is there now some totally new way to indicate what template you want to render now? If so which versions of Rails does it apply to?

Comment: Calling `render :template => "procurements/view_downloads"` is coming up as deprecated in your log file ?

Comment: No, but it would still be great to have more information about the deprecation. Does it just have to do with Rails 3?

Comment: I would venture it could be to do with Rails 3, but yeah, wish there was more info on many aspects of Rails. Can't help you much in that area.

Comment: Do you have the route defined in your routes.rb?  something like: map.resources :procurements, :collection => {:view_downloads => :get}?  I wonder if your controller method is being called at all

Comment: check you server logs to see what's going on...